# How can mysql blobs be edited?

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

Is there a way to edit a blob with mysql, for example to delete from 39th to 48 byte or to insert some bytes (characters), at some position? Are there any such commands.

Comment: You would usually fetch the blob's content into your client application, do the changes there, and save back the entire blob with the changes in it. How are you accessing mySQL?

Comment: php, I know that, but isn't there any faster way?

Comment: Have you done tests? That's probably plenty fast enough.

Comment: ok but what if my blob is 4gb big would it be as fast as with a mysql function?

Comment: Have you tried using string functions like `REPLACE()`, `SUBSTRING()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your blob is extremely large, entering it into the database in the first place is very difficult.

MySQL only allows the maximum packet size to be sent as a command - which makes using large blobs difficult.

If your blobs are big enough that you care, you probably need to create some schema where they're stored as several rows with chunks, to allow them to be created in a sensible fashion.

BUT storing very large blobs is probably not a good idea in MySQL, as it's effectively a massive waste of your innodb_buffer_pool.

NB: By "Very large" I mean > 10M or so.